# Create global keypress from C# application

Tags: c#, vbscript, keyboard-shortcuts, global

I'm trying to do this in C#.

VB Script

```
   set wsh=wscript.createObject("wscript.shell")
   wsh.sendKeys("^C")
```

How could i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always Invoke the method using reflection in c#. Here is an example for the sendKeys that you can also apply to the AutoIt control.

```
var wshType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("wscript.shell");
var wsh = Activator.CreateInstance(wshType);

var whatEver = 
    wsh.GetType().InvokeMember(
        "sendKeys", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
        null, 
        wsh, 
        new string[] { "^C" });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SendKeys.Send()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
SendKeys.Send("^C");
```

Comment: how about the mouse event sir ?

P.S: sry not completing my question yet before.

Comment: You changed the question. I rolled it back. It's unfair to change the question after it has been answered well. Such a simple question, with a simple answer, and then you change it to something utterly different.

Comment: yeah because of that i'm saying sry and still vote up your answer. well, if your pride that much instead helping others that have same problem with me...

Comment: Your true problem is likely best solved by UI Automation

Comment: UI Automation seems restricting itself due several things. I'm more believe in using vbs application method and using it in C#.

Comment: Use autoit if you like. Entirely your choice.